# How to sort on hidden or data-attribute value in textSorter

Tags: tablesorter

I have a "name" column in a table that contains a persons full name (ie. first+last name). The objective is to sort the column based on the person's last name first, then first name. My initial naive approach for the `textsorter` function was

```
function (a, b){
    const aSplit = a.split(' ');
    const bSplit = b.split(' ');
    const aReverse = aSplit[1] + aSplit[0];
    const bReverse = bSplit[1] + bSplit[0];
    return aReverse.localeCompare(bReverse);
}
```

Unfortunately, some of the names I have to sort have extraneous spaces in them, potentially in either the first name or last name field. So I have to support this in my sorting.

I am currently only using the combined first+last name string for display and sorting but I have access to the seperate name strings as well as a preformatted `lastname, firstname` version. I'd like to attach either of these to the `<th>` tags as a data attribute or something like that and sort using that instead of the actual value but I'm not sure how to go about accessing those attributes from within the `textsorter` function.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this - when you build the table HTML, add the last name + first name into a `data-text` attribute of the cell. Tablesorter will automatically use that attribute over the actual text within the cell. See [`textAttribute` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textattribute) to allow changing that attribute name.